# Demasiada data para un StreamedResponse?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando una descarga de información de mi app en un txt generado por Streamed Response.

Me doy cuenta que funciona todo bien, pero con cierta cantidad de información.

Estoy realizando esto:

```
       $encabezado = '';

        $content='';

        $encabezado.='606|'. $cliente->num_documento.'|'. $tiempo->format('Ym').'|'.$count_facturas;

        $encabezado.=  "\r\n";

        echo($encabezado);

        foreach($reportes as $reporte){
            
            $content.= $reporte->documento.'|';
            $content.= $reporte->tipo_documento . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->bienes . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->ncf . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->ncf_modificado . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->date_comp . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->date_pago . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->monto_servicios == 0 ? '|': $reporte->monto_servicios.'|';
            // $content.= $reporte->monto_bienes == 0 ? '|': $reporte->monto_bienes.'|';
            // $content.= $reporte->monto_total == 0 ? '|': $reporte->monto_total.'|';
            $content.=  "\r\n";
            
            echo($content); 
            $content=''; 
    }

    

    $response = new StreamedResponse();

    $response->setCallBack(function () use($content) {

        echo($content);

    });

    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 
    'DGII_F_606_'.$cliente->num_documento.'_'.$tiempo->format('Ym').'.txt');
    
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);

    return $response;
```

Si descomento otra mas de las iteraciones en el foreach, la descarga de la información falla. En cambio si las dejo tal cual funciona.

Esto se debe a que hay mucha información en la respuesta?

Comment: ¿Por qué haces `echo` de encabezados y contenido antes de inicializar `streamedResponse` y fuera de la función `callBack`? ¿Cuántos registros contiene el reporte? Dependiendo de la cantidad de datos, podrías estar consumiendo más memoria de la disponible o excediendo el tiempo límite de ejecución del script.

Comment: @Triby gracias por responder. Hago el echo antes porque todos los ejemplos que he visto lo hacen de la misma manera  y funciona. Ahora mismo son solo 68 registros.

Comment: @Triby tenias mucha razón en cuanto al echo antes de llegar a la función callBack, lo que hice fue solo poner los echo dentro del callBack y aparentemente funcionan todo bien. Muchísimas gracias!